# Need help in fixing redirects. My website is working super slow since yesterday

Tags: magento-1.9

Since yesterday my website is working very slow suddenly I don't know what happen. If I truncate `core_url_rewrite` then it opens fast but then I have to reindex the website to make it function 100%. Now I also used Gtmetrix to scan my website and this is the result I got.

[image: Result]

I really don't know how can i fix this issue, please if anyone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Did you install any module recently? or did you do any changes in configuration? Also can you have a look at console errors and see if you can get some clue there?

Comment: Those redirects look like they are from some 3rd party domain (snapchat).  Do you have some widget that links to that.  You should not have anything on your page that relies on a external domain to load you page

Comment: @AmolBhandariSJ no i didnt install any module, infact we are mitigating to m2 so the free lance developer is working on it, but this problem started yesterday.

Comment: @PaddyD we use snap chat for ads and that also we started recently, besides its pixels we have not linked anything to snapchat. Do you know if there is a way i can delete these links ?'

Comment: How to know with out looking at the full report from Gtmetrix , but my guess that most of the 54s is caused by that snapchat redirecting ( you should be able to see this in the waterfall page), and you site is not actually loading slowly, its the external snapchat that is loading slowly.  Try removing the snapchat add and see if thats resolves this issue ( then you know its that)

Comment: @PaddyD https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.kiabza.com/dtrJoHnu here the full report, sorry for not posting it earlier, let me look into what you said

Comment: @Patrik  I think the snapchat is a red herring, look at the waterfall, its taking the domain 37s to repond and a lot of elements are failing to load at all

Comment: @PaddyD any idea how can i remove this ?

Comment: @Patrik Something more going on that's causing your server to return failed connection.  You would need to look at the server logs to see why they are failing

Comment: @PaddyD i removed snapchat pixels and also cleared sessions files from database, for now its working properly but I need to do more rnd to find the problem.